# Connections does not returned to pool.I am using DB2 9.1 & DB2 9.5

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Connections does not returned to the pool, the size of the connection pool increases more than the maxSize. I am using the `DB2 9.1` and `9.5` both and `Tomcat 7.0.47`.

I am setting `maxSize = "30"` but when I see the database connection log it shows connection more than `30` and it increases to `100` and after that database gets locked. I am using Applet, Servlet & Javabeans (for business logic).

I have configure the Tomcat by changing the `web.xml`, `context.xml` and `server.xml` (which are at the conf directry of the server). The configurations are as follows

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
<resource-ref>
  <description>DB2 Datasource example</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/datasourcename</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

**context.xml**

```
<Context>
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/datasourcename" global="jdbc/datasourcename" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</Context>
```

**server.xml**

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

<!-- DB2 Data Source-->
<Resource name="jdbc/datasourcename" auth="Container" 
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnBorrow="true"
      testOnReturn="false"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1"
      validationInterval="30000"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
      maxActive="30"
      minIdle="1"
      maxWait="10000"
      initialSize="1"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      logAbandoned="true"
      removeAbandoned="true"
      closeMethod="close"  
      abandonWhenPercentageFull="60"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="3000"
      jmxEnabled="true"              jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
      alternateUsernameAllowed="true"
      username="user"
      password="pass"         
      driverClassName="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"         
      url="jdbc:db2:://127.0.0.1:50000/DBname" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

The code where I use some connections and closing it.

```
public Vector getCargo() throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int rec = 0;
    Vector v = new Vector();
    java.sql.Connection tcon = null;
    String tsql = "";
    try {
        tcon = getCon("MO");
        try {
            tsql = "SELECT cargo_cd,cargo_desc FROM mas_cargo ORDER BY cargo_desc";
            ps = tcon.prepareStatement(tsql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                rec++;
                String[] data = new String[2];
                data[0] = rs.getString("cargo_cd");
                data[1] = rs.getString("cargo_desc");
                v.addElement(data);
            }
            if (rec < 1)
                throw new SQLException("No Cargo Available.");
        } catch (SQLException sql) {
            tcon.rollback();
            throw new SQLException("Mas_Cargo Table :\n" + sql.getMessage());
        }
        tcon.commit();
    } catch (SQLException sql) {
        throw new SQLException("Error :\n" + sql.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if (ps != null)
                ps.close();
            if (tcon != null)
                tcon.close();
        } catch (SQLException sql) {
            sql.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

I have used both datasource and Class.forName() separately for getting connection,but in both the case the connection does not releases.(When the datasource method didn't work,I tried Class.forName())

Comment: Are you closing your connections in your code? Without an explicit `close()` connections will not be (or only much later) returned to the pool.

Comment: I have close all my connections in finally block by using connection.close();

Comment: Pls help me to solve the problem

Comment: is there anyone who can give me a suggestion to solve this problem

Comment: Please include some code where you allocate, use and close the connection.

Comment: I have included the code where I allocate, use and close the connection.Pls pls give me a suggestion

Comment: In your current code, if closing the `ResultSet` or `PreparedStatement` fails, you will not close the connection. Make sure they are each in their own try...catch

Comment: can you pls post the corrected code i,e the changes I required to made.I also want to inform that all things are go right if I use Oracle 11g/postgrace database.But it fails in case of DB2 9.1/9.5